# Placing platforms randomly in world with Phaser

Tags: javascript, random, phaser-framework

I'm making a vertical scrolling platform game using Phaser, but I can't figure out how to create randomly placed platforms to jump on. This is the code I have so far (removed unneccesary stuff):

```
Platformer.Game = function (game) {
            this._platforms = null;
            this._platform = null;
            this._numberOfPlatforms = 15;
            this._x = this.x;
            this._y = this.y;
        };

        Platformer.Game.prototype = {
            create: function (){
                this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                this.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 200;

                this._platforms = this.add.group();
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);
                Platformer.platform.createPlatform(this);

                game.camera.follow(this._player);

            },

            managePause: function () {
                this.game.paused = true;
                var pausedText = this.add.text(100, 250, "Game paused. Click anywhere to continue.", this._fontStyle);
                this.input.onDown.add(function(){
                    pausedText.destroy();
                    this.game.paused = false;
                }, this);
            },

            update: function () {

            }
        };

        Platformer.platform = {
            createPlatform: function (game) {
                var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * Platformer.GAME_WIDTH * this._numberOfPlatforms * 70);
                var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * Platformer.GAME_HEIGHT * this._numberOfPlatforms * 50);
                var platform = game.add.sprite(posX, posY, 'platform');


                game._platforms.add(platform);
                platform.events.onOutOfBounds.add(this.removePlatform, this);
            },

            removePlatform: function (game) {
                this._platform.kill();
            }

        }
```

I can get it to work to place them randomly, but the idea of a platformer should be you could actually jump on it. With enough distance but not too much, so I guess not entirely random.

Hope you have some ideas!

Comment: Javascript or [Java](http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java)?

Comment: Javascript :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, my confusion was because [tag:phaser] is for Java, and the correct tag to use here is (apparently ;) [tag:phaser-framework].

Comment: No-one able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach, just a start really.

The idea is to build up some basic rules basing the position of each platform on the one that came before. For example, if the last one was on the left, put the next one somewhere to the right.

Min/max ranges are also good in these situations: In this example the next platform is always at least 200px higher up than the last and no more than 300px higher.

There's a [playable example here on codepen](http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/cfFIi)

```
platforms = game.add.group();
platforms.enableBody = true;
platforms.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

// start off on the left 220px above the ground
var x = 0, y = height - 220;

// keep adding platforms until close to the top
while(y > 200) {
  var platform = platforms.create(x, y, 'platform');
  platform.body.immovable = true;
  platform.body.allowGravity = false;

  // find center of game canvas
  var center = width / 2;

  if(x > center) {
    // if the last platform was to the right of the 
    // center, put the next one on the left
    x = Math.random() * center;
  }
  else {
    // if it was on the left, put the next one on the right
    x = center + Math.random() * (center - platformWidth);
  }
  // place the next platform at least 200px higher and at most 300px higher 
  y = y - 200 - 100 * Math.random();
}
```